# R - Subset of matrix based on cell value of one column

Tags: r, split, subset

**Hi there**

I have this matrix (is.matrix(users)=TRUE) with X users and 7 columns. The first column indicates male/female with either a 0 or a 1. How can I split this matrix into two new matrices. One with all the boys scores and one with all the girls scores.

**I Have**

USERS

*All users*

```
         sex     intelligence   ...    status  
user1      0             1234   ...       ...
user2      1             5678   ...       ...
user3      1             8765   ...       ...
...      ...              ...   ...       ...
userX      0             4321   ...       ...
```

**I need**

*BOYS*

```
         sex     intelligence   ...    status  
user2      1             5678   ...       ...
user3      1             8765   ...       ...
```

*GIRLS*

```
         sex     Intelligence   ...    status  
user1      0             1234   ...       ...
userX      0             4321   ...       ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `split`

```
lst <- setNames(lapply(split(1:nrow(mat1), mat1[,"sex"]), function(i) mat1[i,]), c("GIRLS", "BOYS"))
```

If you need two datasets instead of keeping it in a list (I would prefer to have it in a list)

```
 list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
 <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
 GIRLS
 #      sex intelligence
 #[1,]   0         1236
 #[2,]   0         1241


 BOYS
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(42)
 mat1 <- as.matrix(data.frame(sex=sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE), intelligence=1234:1243))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert matrix to dataframe and subset it

```
df <- as.data.frame(users)
girls <- df[df$sex == 0, ]
boys <- df[df$sex == 1, ]
```

If you need matrix again:

```
girls <- as.matrix(girls)
boys <- as.matrix(boys)
```

Comment: I would like to keep it as matrices and vectors since I've heard that for large datasets, that should be faster to work with than data frames

Comment: if you work with really large dataset, I suggest you using `data.table` [more info](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki).

Comment: @adomasb I guess you don't need to convert/reconvert to data.frame.  `indx <- !mat1[,"sex"];  mat1[indx,]; mat1[!indx,]` (`mat1` is from my example)

Comment: yes, it is definitely not necessary, however, there are hundreds of approaches :). I only use matrix class just for matrix multiplications, I prefer `data.table` (formerly `data.frame`), therefore I used `data.frame` approach.